# VLOOKUP in Google Sheets returns the wrong thing

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

So I have a Google Sheet and I'm trying to make a Rock, Paper, Scissors game.
Everything works for now, but I'm missing a way to check who wins. I thought of having a range of cells and then use a `VLOOKUP` to find the winner. But it sometimes returns the wrong thing.

The cells are these:

[image: Range of cells]

The left and middle are the ones to check through, and the one on the right would be the winner.

I tried this:
`=IF(B2 = J2, "Tie!", VLOOKUP({B2, J2}, X1:Z3, 3, FALSE))`
where `B2` and `J2` are the player's choices, and `X1:Z3` is the range mentioned above.
It works most of the time, but sometimes it returns the wrong thing, like:

[image: Returns the wrong thing]

Everyone knows that Rock wins Scissors, so **that is wrong**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`VLOOKUP` cannot search for multiple search_keys. So, you can combine the search key into a single search_key.
I use `b2&j2` So we can modify formula and table

`=IF(B2 = J2, "Tie!",VLOOKUP(B2&J2, ARRAYFORMULA({X1:X6&Y1:Y6,Z1:Z6}), 2, FALSE))`

[image]

Please review it: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XGCLY8-lkozE7Fj-ZWmHHnTcMx7XjZJWPB9PWxHLAOs/edit?usp=sharing